# What is the antonym of "silent" when we say "the letter b in lamb is silent"?

Tags: word-request

Today I want to ask my friend if the letter `t` in his name is silent or not (because he has a foreign name unlike the typical English names I've seen).

I asked "Is the letter `t` in your name silent or not?" **But now I'm wondering if there is a single adjective I can use as the antonym of "silent."**

Probably I could have also said "Is the letter `t` in your name silent or pronounced?" But "pronounced" doesn't seem to be an adjective.

Comment: "Do you pronounce the letter 't' in your name, or is it silent?"

Comment: 'pronounced' is fine in that context, but I've also heard '... silent or sounded?'.

Comment: also "vocalized"

Comment: For the letter "h" and similar sounds in other languages, you can say that it is [aspirated](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/aspiration).

Answer (score 2):

"Pronounced" is fine or "sounded", "said" or "vocalised" are also possible. In your context

> Is the letter 't' silent?

Is still the best sentence, but you could have asked

> Is the letter 't' sounded? /  Do you pronounce the 't'? / How is the 't' pronounced in your name? / How do you say your name?

Answer (score 1):

The word I am used to seeing in this circumstance is 'voiced., as in "Is the letter 't' voiced?" ('sounded' comes off very odd to me - used to western US English).

Comment: The problem with "voiced" is that it has a technical linguistic meaning that the vocal chords are engaged. In standard English, the letter 't' is never "voiced", even when it makes a sound, because the sound is produced solely by the tongue and teeth, not by the vocal chords.